# Archiva Remote repository issue

Tags: apache, repository, archiva

I am trying to add a remote repository on Archiva. However, I keep getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZExC.png) in the logs:

> ERROR `org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.JAXRSUtils` []
>   - No message body
>   writer has been found for class
>   `org.apache.archiva.rest.services.ArchivaRestError`,
>   ContentType: text/plain

I tried adding the Content Type header with text/plain but that did not work

Comment: Does it happen when you use the UI? Or you're doing your own rest call?

Comment: It occurs when I use the UI

Comment: This error also occurs when I enter a random url as well

Answer (score 4):

I've hit the same problem after adding a new remote repository to Archiva.

From my analysis I conclude that the error is thrown for Repositories that don't expose an index.

Example:
When adding http://download.oracle.com/maven, which is Oracle's Maven Repository to receive artifacts, will throw this error as soon as you've added it as a remote repository.

Trying to access the URL via browser results in a 404.
However, direct queries like [this](http://download.oracle.com/maven/com/sleepycat/je/5.0.104/je-5.0.104.pom) are answered properly.

So, I guess it is Archiva's inability to properly cope with such repositories.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same issue as described with Apache Archiva 2.2.0.

Apache Archiva 2.2.3 appears to be fix this issue, and appears to be a drop-in replacement which works with all of the configuration and databases from 2.2.0.

https://archiva.apache.org/download.cgi

Answer (score 0):

Seems that archiva 2.2.1 always adds // at the end of the remote repo url.

On some repos, this results in errors (e.g. Maven Central returns code 400 for http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2///).

Some other repos ignore the trailing slashes and still work (nexus).

ps: as long as I used a lan proxy, I did not had the problem. I guess it translates the url and removes those extra slashes, which avoids the whole problem.